# Giving Read Unread effect in ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview

i was working with a customised ListView and I'm Trying to get the email read/unread effect(i.e. Bold while read). Since I'm using cursor adapter I'm not able to crack it; Here's my code

```
String[] from = new String[]
        { 
        cursor.getColumnName(4), 
        cursor.getColumnName(3),
        cursor.getColumnName(1),
        cursor.getColumnName(2),
        cursor.getColumnName(7),
        cursor.getColumnName(o)
        //,cursor.getColumnName(10)
        //cursor.getColumnName(columnIndex)
        };
      int[] to = new int[] 
        { 
        R.id.pay_freq, 
        R.id.tax_period,
        R.id.tax_date, 
        R.id.tax_year, 
        R.id.net_pay,
        R.id.row_id
        };
      strGetReadorNot = cursor.getString(10);            
      if(strGetReadorNot.equals("0"))
      {
       setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
      }
      else
      {

      }
      //Adapter used as interface between the widget and String array
      adapters = new SimpleCursorAdapter(PayslipListActivity.this, R.layout.list_items,cursor, from, to);
      setListAdapter(adapters);
```

Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a custom CursorAdapter.

In `bindView()` check if the email is read and set your textView's typeface.

Comment: Unfortunately my TextView is in another layout, so i cant call any of its control here :( any other ideas?

Comment: I know that's why I'm suggesting you use a **custom** cursoradapter. Check out this [example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1057)

Comment: With some references, I did it; Working well Thnx Ma8:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder` and when you bind each `View`, check if the mail is unread/read and set the `TextView` Style to bold accordingly.